# Help with regular expression - DateTime validation in XSD

Tags: regex, xsd

I have the following:

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime">
   <xsd:pattern value="[1-9][0-9]{3}\-.+T[^\.]+(Z|[\+\-].+)"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

I then get an error when I use something like this: `2011-06-167T09:30:47.0Z` or this:`2011-06-16T09:30:47.0Z`

Could you please help me figure out what is wrong with the datetime I am validating?

I do not control the XSD with the RegEx - all I can do is to make my dates comply with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the regex itself should accept the date. However, does `xsd:dateTime` pose any restrictions in regard to invalid dates? (day = `167`)?

Comment: Hi jensgram, I fixed the day to simply 16 and it still errors-out. Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}-.+T[^.]+(Z|[+-].+)
```

(unnecessary escapes removed) fails because your test string doesn't fulfill the rules of the regex which are:

```
[1-9][0-9]{3} # match a four-digit number > 999        : 2011 
-             # dash                                   :     -
.+            # one or more unspecified characters     :      06-167
T             # a T                                    :            T 
[^.]+         # one or more characters except dot      :             09:30:47
(             # followed by either                     :
 Z            # a Z                                    :                     ???
|             # or                                     :
 [+-]         # a plus or minus sign                   :                     ???
 .+           # and one or more unspecified characters :
)
```

Your test string `2011-06-167T09:30:47.0Z` does contain a dot before the `Z` (and there is no plus/minus sign that would allow the alternative to match) so the regex fails.

The question is: What are the rules you do need to follow? How are datetimes defined in your application?

Comment: Tim, this is very useful. Big thanks! Here's where I am - my client provides me with XML file to submit to a Web Service, which validates the XML against the XSD. The XML file has the dates and the XSD has the expression. I assume I can have them generate the xml files with whatever date format that the Web Service accepts, but I am not sure if ...09:30:470Z would be a valid time.

Comment: Well, as long as the time part doesn't contain a dot, everything should be fine. Since you can't change the regex to a more sensible one, how about having the XML generator use a comma instead of a dot to signify fractions of a second (or just drop those altogether if you don't need that precision)?

Comment: General schema validation error: The element is invalid - The value '2011-06-167T09:30:47Z' is invalid according to its datatype 'DateTime' - The string '2011-06-167T09:30:47Z' is not a valid XsdDateTime value.

Comment: @Gustavo Cavalcanti: Note that restrictions of the base type apply to the restricted type. Value `2011-06-167T09:30:47Z` is invalid because it is not a valid value for the basetype (xsd:dataTime) of your restricted type. Part `-167T` doesn't match the requirements `-ddT`. Overall, your regex has a lot of unneeded restrictions, because the only restriction it really adds to `xs:dateTime` is that year must be >= 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a non greedy matching, perhaps that solves it:

```
<xsd:pattern value="[1-9][0-9]{3}\-.+?T[^\.]+?(Z|[\+\-].+)"/>
```

With the ? after a + it searches for the smallest possible not the longest possible part of .

Futhermore I'mk not sure if that works, as you want it to:

```
[^\.]
```

Try without the ^

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I do not own the XSD containing the expression and cannot change it.